# Update birthdate incase the date is Hijri by the value of converting hijri birthdate to Gregorian

Tags: sql, gregorian-calendar, hijri

Table contains many records with Hijri date value and Gregorian value in BirthDate column, so please how to update Birthdate by the value of converting Hijri date to Gregorian
thanks
I tried this script but it dosen't work - I meant no changes - although I get

### (18422 row(s) affected)

```
UPDATE MEMBER
SET BIRTHDATE = case when (SUBSTRING(cast(birthdate as nvarchar), 1, 2) ='14') 
or 
(SUBSTRING(cast(birthdate as nvarchar), 1, 2) ='13')
then 
(SELECT CONVERT(date, birthdate , 131) ) 
else
 birthdate
 end
```

Comment: What datatype is `birthdate`?

Comment: Well yeah, even `UPDATE member SET birthday = birthday` would give "(18422 row(s) affected)". What is the actual effect of your query? Does it set any records to wrong values?

Comment: No changes, all records for the column birthdate as it is, that meant it is still in hijri date with same old value, birthdate type is date

Answer (score 0):

try the below code it will convert birthdate column records into Hijri format:

update MEMBER
set BIRTHDATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),birthdate,131) --- [Hijri date to Gregorian date]

update MEMBER
set BIRTHDATE = CONVERT(datetime, birthdate, 131) --- [ Gregorian date to Hijri date]

There are several blogs about this, likethis one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wael/archive/2007/04/29/sql-server-hijri-hijra-dates.aspx

Comment: I go through this page before I have asked this question and it is not solving my problem, by the way I didn't get any error message, instead of that I get records updated message, thanks